# Where can I find a dataset of social bots from other source than twitter?

Tags: data-request, social-media

It's easy to find datasets of bots (fake accounts) from twitter, but I can't find similar datasets of bots from another social media (like facebook, instagram, reddit, linkedin...)

Is there any published?

Comment: Not sure, but you might look into Discord bots and Twitch's "nightbot", but I have no idea if they publish any useful stats